# Replication Error on UPDATE query.

Tags: mysql, replication

I have setup many mysql replications but this is the first time i am seeing a replication error on an `UPDATE` query.

`Error 'Duplicate entry '6698461' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'email_app'. Query:`

```
 update email_app.msg_in m 
 LEFT JOIN animProfiles ap ON m.senderID_out=ap.senderID 
 set m.animID='924' 
 where (ap.chatter=0 OR ap.chatter=924) AND m.senderID_in='86625'
```

can anyone point out what would cause such a query to have a conflict with an existing primary key? In my past experience its always been a `INSERT` query that would cause this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i figure it out. I had A trigger for the UPDATE event in this table which does an INSERT TO another table. That table already had a duplicate entry. :)